# How do I view a recipe on a chef server?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

```
knife search node '*:*' -a recipes
```

gives me all the nodes and their recipes.

```
knife node show NODE_ID -a recipes
```

gives me recipes used by a specific node with `NODE_ID`.

I need to fetch the contents of the recipes that these commands fetch. Even a command to view a specific recipe on the chef server would suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`knife cookbook show COOKNAME VERSION recipes RECIPENAME.rb`

You can also tweak that for other types of files inside a cookbook.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `knife cookbook show COOKBOOK [VERSION] [PART] [FILENAME]` command:

```
knife cookbook show mycookbook 1.2.3 recipes default.rb
```

outputs the default recipe of *mycookbook*'s version 1.2.3